# Bundle arguments returning null

Tags: android, sqlite, arguments, fragment, bundle

I'm trying to send some data from an SQLite database to a fragment via a bundle.

The debugger is showing that the `cursor` is returning all columns like it should, but the `StringArrays` are null when adding them to the bundle.

Any ideas as to why this is?

**UPDATE**

That seems ok, but it's throwing `null pointer exception` in the fragment.

Line 46 is `String[] Name = args.getStringArray(names);`

See LOGCAT:

```
12-04 13:55:41.812 5379-5379/com.example.michael.budgetapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.michael.budgetapp, PID: 5379
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.example.michael.budgetapp.Tabs.Transactions.TransactionsTab.onCreateView(TransactionsTab.java:46)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Fragment Class:

```
public class TransactionsTab extends Fragment {

RecyclerView transactionsRecycler;
AdapterTransactions adapter;
TransactionLoad transactionLoad = null;
private Cursor data = null;
List<TransactionInfo> adapterData = new ArrayList<>();
String names, categories, currencies, prices, dates;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    transactionLoad = new TransactionLoad(getActivity());
    transactionLoad.execute();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_transactions, container, false);
    transactionsRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.transactionRecycler);
    adapter = new AdapterTransactions(getActivity(), adapterData);
    transactionsRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    transactionsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    transactionLoad = new TransactionLoad(getActivity());
    transactionLoad.execute();

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    String[] Name = args.getStringArray(names);
    String[] Category = args.getStringArray(categories);
    String[] Currency = args.getStringArray(currencies);
    String[] Price = args.getStringArray(prices);
    String[] Date = args.getStringArray(dates);
    for (int i = 0;
         i < Name.length &&
         i < Category.length &&
         i < Currency.length &&
         i < Price.length &&
         i < Date.length;
         i++) {
        TransactionInfo info = new TransactionInfo();
        info.itemName = Name[i];
        info.itemCat = Category[i];
        info.itemCurrency = Currency[i];
        info.itemPrice = Price[i];
        info.date = Date[i];
        adapterData.add(info);
        }
    adapter.setData(adapterData);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    adapter.transactionData.notifyAll();

    return view;
}
```

[image]

```
String names, categories, currencies, prices, dates;

@Override
public void transactionLoadComplete(Cursor cursor) {
    tData = cursor;
    while (tData.moveToNext()) {
        String[] Name = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NAME};
        String[] Category = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CATEGORY};
        String[] Currency = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY};
        String[] Price = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_PRICE};
        String[] Date = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE};

        String names = tData.getString(tData.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_NAME));
        String categories = tData.getString(tData.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CATEGORY));
        String currencies = tData.getString(tData.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_CURRENCY));
        String prices = tData.getString(tData.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_PRICE));
        String dates = tData.getString(tData.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.TRANSACTION_DATE));

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArray(names, Name);
        args.putStringArray(categories, Category);
        args.putStringArray(currencies, Currency);
        args.putStringArray(prices, Price);
        args.putStringArray(dates, Date);
        TransactionsTab transactionsTab = new TransactionsTab();
        transactionsTab.setArguments(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: You declared `names, categories, currencies, prices, dates` but did not initialize them. Your string arrays are fine.

Comment: You never read anything out of `tData`.

Comment: in 'args.putStringArray(names, Name)' you never set what the key 'names' is. What you have is args.putStringArray(null, Name). Note the first argument is the key and the second argument is the value. The variable Name is always the same array of type String, an array with one cell of value DatabaseHelper.TRANSITION_NAME.  To get data out of the cursor you have to specify the column data you want. String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name"));

Comment: I think that worked for one thing, if I did it correctly. `NullPointerException` being thrown in the `Fragment` now. Updated OP.